# Write text on sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a grid with sprites in Unity. Each cell should have a number on it.

This is how it should look

[image]

and my grid looks this

[image]

So I generate the cells and add them to a empty gameobject called

> Map

```
private GameObject cellPrefab;

private const int CELL_COUNT_X = 10; // create 100 cells
private const int CELL_COUNT_Y = 10;
private const float CELL_SPACING = 1.1f; // with a small spacing

private List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>(); // store all cells here

private const int NUM_RANGE_MIN = 1; // cell value range
private const int NUM_RANGE_MAX = 10;

private void Start()
{
    cellPrefab = Resources.Load(StringCollection.CELL) as GameObject;

    for (int x = 0; x < CELL_COUNT_X; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < CELL_COUNT_Y; y++)
        {
            float spawnPosX = x * CELL_SPACING - CELL_COUNT_X / 2;
            float spawnPosY = y * CELL_SPACING - CELL_COUNT_Y / 2;
            GameObject cell = Instantiate(cellPrefab, new Vector2(spawnPosX, spawnPosY), cellPrefab.transform.rotation); // create the new cell

            cell.transform.SetParent(transform); // add the cell to the map

            Cell cellComponent = cell.GetComponent<Cell>();

            cellComponent.InitCell(Random.Range(NUM_RANGE_MIN, NUM_RANGE_MAX)); // init the cell value

            cells.Add(cellComponent); // add to list
        }
    }
}
```

Each cell got this script attached

```
private Text txtCellValue;
private int cellValue;

public void InitCell(int value)
{
    txtCellValue = transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>(); // get the text component of the cell
    cellValue = value; // set the value
    txtCellValue.text = cellValue.ToString(); // update the GUI
}
```

So in the hierarchy, each cell is added to the "Map" and got this own hierarchy

[image]

The canvas is set on "Scale with Screensize" and the text itself has these settings

[image]

**I just want to write the value of the cell on this sprite. Maybe there is a more clean way?**

Would be nice if someone could help fixing this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will select render mode "world" for your canvas. Then set the scale and width/height values.

Also, you will remember about sorting layers. Canvas layer would be bigger than sprite renderer, if you dont use separate camera for UI.